# Objective-C NSArray Access

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

It seems that in `Objective-C` there are two ways to access an `NSArray`. I could access the 'i'th element of `NSArray` 'array' by:

```
array[i]
```

or

```
[array objectAtindex:i]
```

Is there any functional difference between these two options?

Comment: @luk2302 - The first is actually an *object subscripting* expression, it is certainly not a *literal* which has [a very specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) in programming languages. Note: Objective-C's array and dictionary "literals" are not really literals either, but *expressions* - Apple tends to be a bit fuzzy when it comes to formal specs ;-(, so don't worry about this and feel free to think me pedantic :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is <s>no</s> a slight difference.

The shorter version uses `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` as opposed to `objectAtIndex:`. These methods are identical in their effect, but you can implement `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` in your own classes to allow element access with the `[index]` syntax.

The shorter version is probably an instance of the "modern Objective-C syntax".

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html) for some more information on the modern syntax and other changes.

See [this other link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for information on Objective-C literals, courtesy of @luk2302.

Comment: Well there is *some* difference.  The first calls `[NSArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:]` and the second calls `[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`.

Comment: @trojanfoe according to the [NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndexedSubscript:), these two method are identical.

Comment: They have the same effect, but the code calls a different method. See [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: @trojanfoe Is there a reason for having two methods that do the same thing? I don't understand why two would be provided if they have the same effect.

Comment: It allows any class  to provide element access by implementing `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`.